# TIdSMTP : How to fix the error SSL negotiation Failed

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy, indy10

I've been using Indy to send emails for ages and it always worked well. Currently I'm using Delphi 10.4, with the Indy version that comes with it.

Today when I tried to use a specific server, even with everything setup as usual, I'm getting these exceptions:

> Project myproject.exe raised Exception class EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message 'Error connecting with SSL. error 1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tslv1 alert protocol version

And right after :

> Project myproject.exe raised Exception EIdTLSClientTLSHandShakeFailed with message : 'SSL negotiation failed'

The port is 587 and so far, I've been using the `sslvTLSv1` method on `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Method`.

What should I try to get the sending work, using this specific server?

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, the server in question does not allow TLS 1.0, which is the only version you are enabling. You should be using the IOHandler's `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property instead of its `SSLOptions.Method` property, and then set `SSLVersions` to `[sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2]` so the client may negotiate use of TLS 1.0, 1.1, or 1.2 depending on which one the server allows.

Comment: Thank you Remy, I did not know i could enable several versions ! Will try that now !

Comment: Remy, your response saved me hours of work. Thanks!